# VS2010 : Merge WebSite assemblies as in Web Deployment project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

is it possible to make a single assembly for whole WebSite in Visual Studio 2010?

With [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459) i can do this in VS2008, but it is not compatible with new version..

Comment: I found aspnet_merge tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx), but can i somehow do it automatically??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a new version of WDP for VS 2010 - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89F2C4F5-5D3A-49B6-BCAD-F776C6EDFA63&displaylang=en